Form_for nested profile using Devise on Rails 7 not displaying field
Trying to add a basic Profile username attribute to the devise new form but the username field is not rendering on screen.
The devise registrations/new.html.haml
= form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: registration_path(resource_name)) do |f|
  .form-group
    = f.label :email, "Email"
    = f.email_field :email, autofocus: true, class: "form-control"

  - f.fields_for :profile do |profile_form|
    .form-group
      = profile_form.label :username, "Username"
      = profile_form.text_field :username, class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.label :password, "Password"
    = f.password_field :password, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control"

  .form-group
    = f.label :password_confirmation, "Confirm Password"
    = f.password_field :password_confirmation, autocomplete: "new-password", class: "form-control"


  .actions
    = f.submit "Sign up", class: "btn btn-primary"

user model:
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

  has_one :profile
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :profile, allow_destroy: true
end

profile model:
class Profile < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
end

registrations controller:
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  private

  def sign_up_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, profile_attributes: [:username])
  end

  def account_update_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:email, :password, :password_confirmation, :current_password, profile_attributes: [:username])
  end
end

Ive tried a lot of things - this is what I am currently looking at code-wise.
Any advice would be helpful.

Change - f.fields_for :profile to = f.fields_for :profile. From the Docs: "The hyphen character is also followed by Ruby code. This code is evaluated but not inserted into the document." whereas  "The equals character is followed by Ruby code. This code is evaluated and the output is inserted into the document." since you need the output included you need to use =

Another way to put it is that - is roughly equivilent to <% in erb while = is equivilent to <%=.

Added to registrations_controller
  def new
    build_resource({})
    resource.build_profile # This ensures a Profile object is created for the user
    respond_with resource
  end

I needed to build the profile

The better way to do this is to pass a block to the super method instead of reimplementing the whole method: def new; super { |resource| resource.build_profile }; end.  https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/blob/72884642f5700439cc96ac560ee19a44af5a2d45/app/controllers/devise/registrations_controller.rb#L11
